# rvest - select href tag string

Tags: css, r, css-selectors, rvest

I am using `rvest`.

```
> pgsession %>% jump_to(urls[2])  %>%  read_html() %>% html_nodes("a")
{xml_nodeset (114)}
 [1] <a href="/Mitglieder/Detail/1213412">Date</a>
 [2] <a href="/Account/ChangePassword">Kennwort Ã¤ndern</a>
 [3] <a href="/Account/BenutzernamenAendern/124312234">Benutzernamen Ã¤ndern</a>
 [4] <a href="/Account/LogOff">Abmelden</a>
...
```

However, I would only like to get all tags that have the href tag `Mitglieder/Detail` in it back.

For example a result should look like that :

```
 [1] /Mitglieder/Detail/1213412
...
```

I tried f.ex.: `a[href~=\"Mitglieder\` as css selector, but I get nothing back as a result.

Any suggestions how to change this css selector?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: `html_nodes('a:contains("Mitglieder")')` does not work for me, `html_nodes(xpath="//a[contains(@href, 'Mitglieder')]")` does. As CSS selectors are translated to XPath selectors anyway, why not go with xpath.

Comment: Thx for your answer, BUT this gives me the full string back. So for example: `<a href="/Mitglieder/Detail/1213412">Date</a>`. I just would like to have `/Mitglieder/Detail/1213412`. I appreciate your reply!

Comment: Add `%>% html_attr("href")`?